# execSQL wont run SQL statement from an Asset

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public void execSqlFromAssets(String path) {
    InputStream input;
    String text;
    try {
        input = mCtx.getAssets().open(path + ".txt");
        int size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();
        text = new String(buffer);
        String[] inserts = text.split(";");
        // SQLiteDatabase db = mDb;
        for (String insert : inserts) {
            insert = insert;
            Log.w(TAG, insert);
            try {
                mDb.execSQL(insert);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String err = (e.getMessage() == null) ? "Cant execute sql"
                        + insert : e.getMessage();
                Log.w(TAG, err);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "execSqlFromAssets: " + path + " file not found");
    }

}
```

This is my code problem is on line that contains **mDb.execSQL(insert)**. it throws exception which i can't read value is null. I just dont get it one of the error messages is:
**Cant execute sqlINSERT INTO food (name, cals) VALUES ("kolac",270)** .
Any help is appreciated

Comment: please post the solution as an answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as @Preet Sangha requested i ll post solution.
My problem was that i called this function in SQLiteOpenHelper instance in onCreate method and 
mDb instance wasnt yet created so i changed function to this

```
public void execSqlFromAssets(String path, SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if(db == null){
        db = mDb;
    }
    InputStream input;
    String text;
    try {
        input = mCtx.getAssets().open(path + ".txt");
        int size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();
        text = new String(buffer);
        String[] inserts = text.split(";");
        for (String insert : inserts) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(insert);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String err = (e.getMessage() == null) ? "Cant execute sql"
                        + insert : e.getMessage();
                Log.w(TAG, err);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "execSqlFromAssets: " + path + " file not found");
    }

}
```

so now if i'm calling this function from onCreate i ll send db as as second argument and if im calling it from other component of application i'll send null as second argument

Comment: if you want i can copy entire class